# Sed replace line stored in a variable

Tags: shell, sed

I need to find a line that starts with `mysql.unmetric.twt.url` and replace the entire line with line stored in the variable ip.

```
ip="mysql.unmetric.twt.url=jdbc:mysql://ec2-a-b-c-d.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/unmetric? jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true"
```

How can this be achieved using sed?

Comment: Crossposting: http://serverfault.com/questions/658378/sed-and-replace

Comment: I tried doing sed -i "s/^mysql.unmetric.all.url/$ip/g" filename but that did not work. Could you please help

Answer (score 1):

There are two stages: first you need to escape any special characters in `$ip`:

```
echo $ip|sed 's#[./&?]#\\&#g'
```

Then you need to perform the substitution:

```
sed -i "s/^mysql\.unmetric\.twt\.url.*$/replacement/g" filename
```

Together these give:

```
sed -i "s/^mysql\.unmetric\.twt\.url.*$/$(echo $ip|sed 's#[./&?]#\\&#g')/g" filename
```

Note that the double quotes for the main substitution are important, so that the replacement string will be interpreted.

Comment: you can use action `c` that dont need so much translation (only new lines if any, and not in this case)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu - What do you mean by "action`c`"? I don't know that command, it's not installed by default in Ubuntu, and it's not an easy name to search for. Or is it an option of `sed` (which my version doesn't include)?

Comment: `c` is a sed action that 'change the content of the line (working buffer in fact) by following content'. It replace the current line/content by the line following `c`, new lines of futur content are replaced by `\` so several line could be used for replacement.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu - OK, thanks. I've not used that command, but I'll keep it in mind for future reference.