# Sed and Replace

Tags: sed

I need to find a line that starts with mysql.unmetric.twt.url and replace the entire line with line stored in the variable ip

ip="mysql.unmetric.twt.url=jdbc:mysql://ec2-a-b-c-d.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/unmetric? jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true"

how can this be achieved using sed , kindly help me with that

Regards

Prashanth

Comment: This is more appropriate for SuperUser. Which language are you using?

Comment: I already answered this at http://superuser.com/questions/862625/sed-replace-line-stored-in-a-variable/862638#862638. Where has my answer gone?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "/^mysql.unmetric.twt.url/ c\\
${ip}" YourFile
```

- Note the double `\\` due to shell substitution with double quote
- double quote for replacing ip by the content